# Decomposition into second normal form

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I got following Relation in first normal form:
R(A,B,C,D,E,F) with ABC candidate key and AB->DE, C->E as functional dependencies

Is the decomposition:
R1(A,B,E)
R2(C,E)
R3(A,B,C,F)

are there ways to prevent the resulting redundancy with E? (Means that E appears twice in R1 and R2 when I decomposite R to bring it into second normal form)

Comment: Maybe you are saying ABC is a CK and that those other two FDs hold, and that only the FDs that follow from those two facts hold? (I thought from your first sentence that the only FDs were those following from the two FDs, which contradicts that ABC is a CK. Your further comments don't clarify. Eg Why *derive* that ABC is a CK as an explanation that it is a CK if you were *given* that it is a CK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. About the question**

> I got following Relation in first normal form...

Each relation is already in first normal form by definition, so it is not necessary to specify it.

> R(A,B,C,D,E,F) with ABC candidate key and AB->DE, C->E as functional dependencies.

If the *only* non-trivial dependencies in R are the two specified, than ABC is not a candidate key (since F is missing). On the other hand, if ABC *is* a candidate key this means that in the relation there is some other dependencies such that from them *plus* the other two dependencies we can derive in some way that ABC -> F (and so that ABC is a key). But we do not known which are the other dependencies, and this prevents a correct normalization. Keep in mind that usually a normalization process starts from a set of functional dependencies and not from the information: “XYZ is a candidate key” plus “there are the other functional dependencies f1, f2, fn.”

To be explicit, in you case for instance you can have another dependency C -> F so that the key *is* ABC, or a dependency ABC -> F, and also in this case the key *is* ABC, but the result of the normalization will be completely different.

**2. About the decomposition**

Here I will give a few consideration about the rest of your question.

You say:

> is the decomposition: R1(A,B,E) R2(C,E) R3(A,B,C,F)

1. The decomposition that you gave is *not* a correct decomposition, since D is missing, and a decomposition *must* contain all the attributes of the original relation. For this reason it is not possible to say that the decomposition is in any normal form (in other words: it is not in any normal form since it is not correct).
2. The second normal form is not an important decomposition and it is presented in the textbooks on databases mostly for historical reasons. There are no formal algorithm to produce it. The most used in practice are the third normal form and the Boyce-Codd normal form. There are also the 4th and 5th normal forms, but they are not very often used in practice, although for certain people they should be.
3. You seem to think that if an attribute appears more than once in the decomposed relations than there is a redundancy. Unless special cases, a decomposition of a relation in any (significant) normal form will *always* produces attributes that are present in more than one relation: in fact this is the *only way* to produce correct decompositions (and this is what foreign keys are for!). There is nothing really “redundant” in this process (on the contrary, a normalization process is used to eliminate or at least reduce the redundancy of the data).

**UPDATED**

Assuming that we start with the three functional dependencies (or any equivalent set of functional dependencies):

```
A B -> D E
C -> E
A B C -> D E F
```

The decomposition:

R1(A,B,D,E) R2(C,E) R3(A,B,C,F)

is in Boyce-Codd normal form (so it is also in 3NF and in 2NF) (and preserves the dependencies).

Finally, we can note that other decompositions in BCNF are possible, for instance with the “analysis” algorithm we can produce the following decomposition, in which the attribute E is not replicated:

R1(A B D E)  R2 (A B C F)

but in this case the dependency C -> E is lost.

Comment: PS Given a CK, we know that it functionally determines all attributes. So maybe one is supposed to assume only the FDs that follow from that. PPS FD decompositions share columns; but JD decompositions don't necessarily.

Comment: @philipxy, you are right, I too do not understand how it is possible to give an exercise as that described in the question. About your PS: possibly you are right. About your PPS: yes, of course, so I talked about “special cases"!

Comment: I really missed the D in R1 sry for that; I didn't notice that the part that isn't clear is that ABC as candidate key is given and the additional dependencies.  The sentence "I got following Relation in first normal form: R(A,B,C,D,E,F) with ABC candidate key and AB->DE, C->E as functional dependencies" is very clear to me. Means, all that stuff is given bc. it is what I have.

Comment: @baxbear As Renzo says, there are lots of ways that ABC could be a CK with those FDs holding. The only thing that makes sense is that (as I wrote in my last comment on your question) you are supposed to assume only the FDs that *must* hold when ABC is a CK and those other 2 FDs hold. That is so subtle it make for a bad question.